# The reference number is inconsistent to the caption number after using \setcounter command

Tags: cross-referencing, counters

I use `\setcounter` command to reset the algorithm number. However, when I use `\ref` command to quote this algorithm, the displayed number is inconsistent to the number in the title of the algorithm. How can I solve this issue?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{algocf}{2}
\begin{algorithm}
\label{alg}
\caption{An algorithm}
1111
\end{algorithm}

Algorithm \ref{alg}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Place the label after the caption.

Comment: This works well for the problem. However, it seems that the position of the label does not matter if I do not use \setcounter. Could you explain a little bit on why this works? Thank you very much!

Comment: The order does depend. Just add a second algorithm with the wrong order, compile and see what happened to the reference numbers.

Comment: label always has to be after the \caption otherwise you are labelling the section counter not the counter for the float.

Comment: This may be helpful: [Why does an environment's label have to appear after the caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32325)