# Subsubsection table reference is wrong

Tags: tables, cross-referencing

I have problem with referencing a table in my subsubsection of my document. The reference in my paragraph always shows a different number compared to my table.

This is the code I used for creating the table:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{center}
\label{table:6.3}
\begin{tabular}{||c || c | c | c | c||}
\hline
x & y & z & u & b \\ [0.5ex] 
\hline\hline
\hline
Sharpness & 32.7\% & 5.3\% & 24.2\% & 37.8\%\\
\hline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption[xx]
\end{table}
```

and this is the code I used to reference it on my paragraph:

```
blablabla \ref{table:6.3}
```

When compiled, the table shows Table 6.3 but on my paragraph it will reference Table 6.2.3.2 following the numbering of my subsubsection. I want both my paragraph and table reference using the same number.

Comment: Place the `\label`  after the `\caption`.

Comment: Apart from that, the `\caption` is missing its mandatory argument. You might want to use `\caption[<short caption text>]{<long caption text>}` instead. <short caption text> is what's shown in the list of tables, <long caption text> is what is shown in the actual caption.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But I fail to understand why placing it after the \caption do the trick

Comment: For an explanation see here: [Why does an environment's label have to appear after the caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32326/134144)