# Non aligned column in tabular environment

Tags: tables

The following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{mwe,array,booktabs}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{skip=5pt}
\usepackage{chemfig, chemformula}
\usepackage{enumitem} % nuevo paquete 07/Feb/2021

\usepackage{fourier,makecell} % Nuevos paquetes 25/Ene/2021
\usepackage{upgreek} % paquete añadido 27/Abr/2021

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Advantages and disadvantages of synthesis routes to make \ch{TiO_2/Ag} loaded fibers.}
    \begin{tabular}{lp{5.0cm}p{5.0cm}c}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Method} & \textbf{Advantages} & \textbf{Disadvantages}  \\
    \midrule
    Electrospinning & 
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, nolistsep]
    \item Fast synthesis
    \item Higher porosity and surface area of the synthesized fibers
    \item Relative  control over \ch{TiO_2/Ag} particle loading
    \item Several polymers can be electrospun 
    \item The \ch{TiO_2/Ag} particles are embedded in the polymer matrix
    \item Tunable size and shape of the fibers
    \end{itemize} & 
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, nolistsep]
    \item Limited amount of polymer to electrospun 
    \item Low solubility of \ch{TiO_2/Ag} particles in the polymer solution to be electrospun 
    \item Specialized equipment
    \end{itemize} \\
    \midrule
    Immersion & 
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, nolistsep]
    \item Easy and fast method
    \item Good control over the \ch{TiO_2/Ag} particle loading
    \item Low consumption of energy 
    \item Not requires specialized equipment 
    \end{itemize} &
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, nolistsep]
    \item The polymer support could not be compatible with the \ch{TiO_2/Ag} particles
    \item The polymer support must be functionalized before the immersion
    \item The porosity of the polymer support depends on the supplier
    \item The \ch{TiO_2/Ag} particles are just attached to the surface of the fibers
    \end{itemize} \\
    \midrule
    Hydrothermal & 
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, nolistsep]
    \item Easy synthesis   
    \item One-step synthesis 
    \end{itemize} &  
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, nolistsep]
    \item High consumption of energy 
    \item Low control over the \ch{TiO_2/Ag} particle loading
    \item Low production per run
    \item Slow synthesis
    \item Specialized equipment
    \item The \ch{TiO_2/Ag} particles are just attached to the surface of the fibers
    \end{itemize} \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:comparison_synthesis}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

provides the table shown in the picture. As you could see, the first column is not well aligned with the others. I cannot figure how to fix it. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Not related: You have defined 4 columns in the preamble of your tabular but you use only 3...

Comment: I didn't notice. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution wirh the `\compress` command which makes latex believe that entering a cell in the relevant columns, a new minipage is starting:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{mwe,array,booktabs}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{skip=5pt}
\usepackage{chemfig, chemformula}
\usepackage{enumitem} % nuevo paquete 07/Feb/2021

\usepackage{fourier,makecell} % Nuevos paquetes 25/Ene/2021
\usepackage{upgreek} % paquete añadido 27/Abr/2021

    \makeatletter
        \newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
    \makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Advantages and disadvantages of synthesis routes to make \ch{TiO_2/Ag} loaded fibers.}
    \begin{tabular}{l >{\compress}p{5.0cm}>{\compress}p{5.0cm}c}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Method} & \textbf{Advantages} & \textbf{Disadvantages} \\
    \midrule
    Electrospinning &
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, nolistsep]
    \item Fast synthesis
    \item Higher porosity and surface area of the synthesized fibers
    \item Relative control over \ch{TiO_2/Ag} particle loading
    \item Several polymers can be electrospun
    \item The \ch{TiO_2/Ag} particles are embedded in the polymer matrix
    \item Tunable size and shape of the fibers
    \end{itemize} &
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, nolistsep]
    \item Limited amount of polymer to electrospun
    \item Low solubility of \ch{TiO_2/Ag} particles in the polymer solution to be electrospun
    \item Specialized equipment
    \end{itemize} \\
    \midrule
    Immersion &
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, nolistsep]
    \item Easy and fast method
    \item Good control over the \ch{TiO_2/Ag} particle loading
    \item Low consumption of energy
    \item Not requires specialized equipment
    \end{itemize} &
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, nolistsep]
    \item The polymer support could not be compatible with the \ch{TiO_2/Ag} particles
    \item The polymer support must be functionalized before the immersion
    \item The porosity of the polymer support depends on the supplier
    \item The \ch{TiO_2/Ag} particles are just attached to the surface of the fibers
    \end{itemize} \\
    \midrule
    Hydrothermal &
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, nolistsep]
    \item Easy synthesis
    \item One-step synthesis
    \end{itemize} &
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, nolistsep]
    \item High consumption of energy
    \item Low control over the \ch{TiO_2/Ag} particle loading
    \item Low production per run
    \item Slow synthesis
    \item Specialized equipment
    \item The \ch{TiO_2/Ag} particles are just attached to the surface of the fibers
    \end{itemize} \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:comparison_synthesis}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*:
To remove the vertical space at the bottom of cells with lists, you may add a negative vertical space ain leaving the corresponding cells , replacing the table preamble with the following!

`\begin{tabular}{l >{\compress}p{5.0cm}<{\vspace* {-\baselineskip}}>{\compress}p{5.0cm}<{\vspace* {-\baselineskip}}c}`

[image]

Comment: Bonjour, Bernard. Your solution method, which I'll call the implicit-minipage approach, seems not to remove the whitespace at the *bottom* of the cells. (Compare this to the screenshot that's part of my solution, which uses explicit minipages via a bespoke itemize-like environment.) Do you know how to remove the excess whitespace at the bottom of the columns 2 and 3? By the way, the `tabular` environment contains just 3 columns; the fourth column, of type `c`, isn't being used.

Comment: @Mico: I've done it long ago, combining a `nosep` option for the lists and a `<{\vskip …}`, but I don't have time at the moment to check the exact value. I'll check & edit my answer this afternoon (Paris meridian ;o)

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to suggest that you employ the machinery of the [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package -- specifically, the package's `\newlist` and `\setlist` macros -- to create a bespoke itemize-like environment (called `tabitemize` below) which encases itself automatically in a `minipage` environment, thereby letting LaTeX do the work of getting rid of the vertical whitespace that's otherwise inserted automatically above and below "ordinary" `itemize` environments. The code below also executes `\RaggedRight` to suspend full justification of the material in the narrow columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{mwe,array,booktabs}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{skip=5pt}
\usepackage{chemfig, chemformula}
\usepackage{fourier,makecell} % Nuevos paquetes 25/Ene/2021
\usepackage{upgreek} % paquete añadido 27/Abr/2021

%% New:
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for '\RaggedRight' macro
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem} % for '\newlist' and '\setlist` macros
\newlist{tabitemize}{itemize}{1} % create bespoke one-level itemize-like list
\setlist[tabitemize,1]{leftmargin=*,nolistsep, % <-- as before; next 3 lines are new
                       label=\textbullet,
                       before={\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}\RaggedRight},
                       after ={\end{minipage}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Advantages and disadvantages of synthesis routes 
           to make \ch{TiO_2/Ag} loaded fibers.}
  \label{tab:comparison_synthesis}
  \begin{tabular}{@{} lp{5.0cm}p{5.0cm} @{}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Method} & \textbf{Advantages} & \textbf{Disadvantages}  \\
    \midrule
    Electrospinning 
    & 
    \begin{tabitemize}
    \item Fast synthesis
    \item Higher porosity and surface area of the synthesized fibers
    \item Relative  control over \ch{TiO_2/Ag} particle loading
    \item Several polymers can be electrospun 
    \item The \ch{TiO_2/Ag} particles are embedded in the polymer matrix
    \item Tunable size and shape of the fibers
    \end{tabitemize} 
    & 
    \begin{tabitemize}
    \item Limited amount of polymer to electrospun 
    \item Low solubility of \ch{TiO_2/Ag} particles in the 
          polymer solution to be electrospun 
    \item Specialized equipment
    \end{tabitemize} \\
    \midrule
    Immersion 
    & 
    \begin{tabitemize}
    \item Easy and fast method
    \item Good control over the \ch{TiO_2/Ag} particle loading
    \item Low consumption of energy 
    \item Not requires specialized equipment 
    \end{tabitemize} 
    &
    \begin{tabitemize}
    \item The polymer support could not be compatible with 
          the \ch{TiO_2/Ag} particles
    \item The polymer support must be functionalized before 
          the immersion
    \item The porosity of the polymer support depends on the supplier
    \item The \ch{TiO_2/Ag} particles are just attached to 
          the surface of the fibers
    \end{tabitemize} \\
    \midrule
    Hydrothermal 
    & 
    \begin{tabitemize}
    \item Easy synthesis   
    \item One-step synthesis 
    \end{tabitemize} 
    &  
    \begin{tabitemize}
    \item High consumption of energy 
    \item Low control over the \ch{TiO_2/Ag} particle loading
    \item Low production per run
    \item Slow synthesis
    \item Specialized equipment
    \item The \ch{TiO_2/Ag} particles are just attached to 
          the surface of the fibers
    \end{tabitemize} \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you don't have the space before the lists in the cells (however, you still have the space at the bottom: if you want to delete it also, you should use a technic described in one of the other answers of this question...).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{mwe,array,booktabs}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{skip=5pt}
\usepackage{chemfig, chemformula}
\usepackage{enumitem} % nuevo paquete 07/Feb/2021

\usepackage{fourier,makecell} % Nuevos paquetes 25/Ene/2021
\usepackage{upgreek} % paquete añadido 27/Abr/2021

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Advantages and disadvantages of synthesis routes to make \ch{TiO_2/Ag} loaded fibers.}
    \begin{NiceTabular}{lp{5.0cm}p{5.0cm}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Method} & \textbf{Advantages} & \textbf{Disadvantages}  \\
    \midrule
    Electrospinning & 
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, nolistsep]
    \item Fast synthesis
    \item Higher porosity and surface area of the synthesized fibers
    \item Relative  control over \ch{TiO_2/Ag} particle loading
    \item Several polymers can be electrospun 
    \item The \ch{TiO_2/Ag} particles are embedded in the polymer matrix
    \item Tunable size and shape of the fibers
    \end{itemize} & 
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, nolistsep]
    \item Limited amount of polymer to electrospun 
    \item Low solubility of \ch{TiO_2/Ag} particles in the polymer solution to be electrospun 
    \item Specialized equipment
    \end{itemize} \\
    \midrule
    Immersion & 
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, nolistsep]
    \item Easy and fast method
    \item Good control over the \ch{TiO_2/Ag} particle loading
    \item Low consumption of energy 
    \item Not requires specialized equipment 
    \end{itemize} &
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, nolistsep]
    \item The polymer support could not be compatible with the \ch{TiO_2/Ag} particles
    \item The polymer support must be functionalized before the immersion
    \item The porosity of the polymer support depends on the supplier
    \item The \ch{TiO_2/Ag} particles are just attached to the surface of the fibers
    \end{itemize} \\
    \midrule
    Hydrothermal & 
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, nolistsep]
    \item Easy synthesis   
    \item One-step synthesis 
    \end{itemize} &  
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, nolistsep]
    \item High consumption of energy 
    \item Low control over the \ch{TiO_2/Ag} particle loading
    \item Low production per run
    \item Slow synthesis
    \item Specialized equipment
    \item The \ch{TiO_2/Ag} particles are just attached to the surface of the fibers
    \end{itemize} \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{NiceTabular}%
  \label{tab:comparison_synthesis}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 0):

A solution to remove the whitespace before the list is to use the [`V` column type](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-varwidcol) from the `varwidth` package. And to remove the whitespace below the list, the command `\vspace{-\baselineskip}\mbox{}` can be added after every `itemize` environment (I have put it in the column specification following Bernard's answer).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{mwe,array,booktabs}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{skip=5pt}
\usepackage{chemfig, chemformula}
\usepackage{enumitem} % nuevo paquete 07/Feb/2021

\usepackage{fourier,makecell} % Nuevos paquetes 25/Ene/2021
\usepackage{upgreek} % paquete añadido 27/Abr/2021
\usepackage{varwidth}%<--- added

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{Advantages and disadvantages of synthesis routes to make \ch{TiO_2/Ag} loaded fibers.}
    \label{tab:comparison_synthesis}%<---moved here from below
    \begin{tabular}{l *{2}{V{5.0cm}<{\vspace{-\baselineskip}\mbox{}}}}%<---changed
    \toprule
    \textbf{Method} & \textbf{Advantages} & \textbf{Disadvantages}  \\
    \midrule
    Electrospinning 
    & 
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, nolistsep]
        \item Fast synthesis
        \item Higher porosity and surface area of the synthesized fibers
        \item Relative  control over \ch{TiO_2/Ag} particle loading
        \item Several polymers can be electrospun 
        \item The \ch{TiO_2/Ag} particles are embedded in the polymer matrix
        \item Tunable size and shape of the fibers
    \end{itemize}
    & 
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, nolistsep]
        \item Limited amount of polymer to electrospun 
        \item Low solubility of \ch{TiO_2/Ag} particles in the polymer solution to be electrospun 
        \item Specialized equipment
    \end{itemize}
    \\
    \midrule
    Immersion 
    & 
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, nolistsep]
        \item Easy and fast method
        \item Good control over the \ch{TiO_2/Ag} particle loading
        \item Low consumption of energy 
        \item Not requires specialized equipment 
    \end{itemize}
    &
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, nolistsep]
        \item The polymer support could not be compatible with the \ch{TiO_2/Ag} particles
        \item The polymer support must be functionalized before the immersion
        \item The porosity of the polymer support depends on the supplier
        \item The \ch{TiO_2/Ag} particles are just attached to the surface of the fibers
    \end{itemize}
    \\
    \midrule
    Hydrothermal 
    & 
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, nolistsep]
        \item Easy synthesis   
        \item One-step synthesis 
    \end{itemize}
    &  
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, nolistsep]
        \item High consumption of energy 
        \item Low control over the \ch{TiO_2/Ag} particle loading
        \item Low production per run
        \item Slow synthesis
        \item Specialized equipment
        \item The \ch{TiO_2/Ag} particles are just attached to the surface of the fibers
    \end{itemize} 
    \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

Note: It's a good practice to place the `label` command right after the `caption` command. See [Why does an environment's label have to appear after the caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32325/219947).

[image]