LaTeX figure numbering
I have a persistent problem with LaTeX.  The numbering for equations works fine, but for figures I keep getting inconsistent and erroneous numbers.  The aux file shows that identical numbers are often assigned for different figures:
\newlabel{fig:rotationPeriods}{{3}{8}}
\newlabel{fig:plasmaComparison}{{3}{9}}

Can anyone help me out?  Many thanks in advance

Welcome to TeX. Could you add a complete, but minimal, compilable code that shows your issue?

Quite likely you have \label before \caption. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32325/why-does-an-environments-label-have-to-appear-after-the-caption?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C52.9136

Also at least with the standard article and book classes  the expected is \newlabel{foo}{{3}{8}{}{}{}}  not \newlabel{foo}{{3}{8}} Maybe an outdated version?

if you are getting erroneous figure numbers then you have an error in your source document (it could be \label  before \caption or something else) but if you show no code it is hard to tell you where you have made an error

I indeed had \label before \caption!  Swapping those fixed my problem immediately.  Many thanks to egreg.
