# Include tabular in list of tables

Tags: tables, tabularx

I am currently having issues with a very long tabular which I had to divide across several pages (for my purposes `\table` did not work) and which I now want to show up in the list of tables. Is there a good way of doing this? I tried to add `\table` in front of `\tabular`, but this turned out horrible in my landsacpe environment (with no options to fix, at least not for me). Is there a smooth way of getting this done?

I would be very very greatful for any advice, as I have been trying several things unsuccessfully.

Comment: `longtable` provides a multipage version of `tabular` that has a `\caption` command that adds to the list of tables.

Comment: Hello David, thank you very much for your comment. I tried longtable, too, but had several troubles with it. Your comment on 'caption' however got me to google another thread http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31737/caption-on-tabular-environment which shows the solution in my tabular environment without having to change anything. Thank you so much! You got me on the right track.